# Google sheet Script Permission to anyone

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, authorization

i have a google sheet , i wrote two scripts under it. one is "Dependent Dropdown" and another is for "Reset Data" to clear entries. Everything is working fine in my machine. script working ,dropdown also working with no issue.

but i have to share sheet  with my colleague to edit this. i shared sheet with  permission "Anyone with the link can edit".
now my colleagues can edit perfectly BUT those two scripts are not working. 
do i have to set script permission ? or what? help please.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, that's the bottleneck of scripts - each colleague of yours needs to authorize the scripts otherwise they won't work for them.

there are installable triggers - **https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable** but user interference is still needed.

one way would be to create a shared account where scripts are authorized and then every user would use that account to access the spreadsheet